# Can we sell ios Enterprise app

Tags: ios

Our company is planning to make a ios app by using Enterprise development program.
I guess we can not implement in app purchase on enterprise app, so we want purchase need to be done by our website and after that link will be generated and sent to the user's email, then by using email user can install the app. So my question is that can we implement this.

We have already development program but we want to integrate some other functionality in the app which will not be approved by apple, so we are planning to have Enterprise development program.

I have seen many links but none i found which fulfill my requirement. Any suggestion regarding this is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, this is not allowed. Enterprise program is for distributing applications *within your organization*. If you give out the application to third parties, your developer program membership will be canceled and the applications will stop working.

Comment: Hi Sami Kuhmonen, thanks for your reply. Can u please advise some other approach so that i could implement this.